# Search data from file1 in file2 and replace with column 2 data from file1

Tags: awk, sed

I have two files
File 1

```
Create -l Ap -ne BP_v BP_v -cir {1 2 3 4}
Create -l Ap -ne BP_p BP_p -cir {1 2 3 4}
```

File 2

```
BP_v net1
BP_p net2
```

I want to search column 1 data of file1 in file2 and if found I want to replace that with column 2 data in file2.

output as

```
Create -l Ap -ne net1 net1 -cir {1 2 3 4}
Create -l Ap -ne net2 net2 -cir {1 2 3 4}
```

Anybody please help. I tried awk but not clear.
I tried the code

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;b[NR]=$2;next}{$5=b[FNR];$6=b[FNR]}1' File 2 File 1
```

But its replacing line by line

Comment: Please do share your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO else you may get close votes on your question, thank you.

Comment: are you *always* looking at columns 5 & 6 (`file1`) or could the replacement occur anywhere on the line? do you need an exact word match or can you match on a substring, eg, could you match on `xx_BP_v` or `BP_v_3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the values line by line because both files have 2 lines, and  you use `NR` and `FNR` to index into the array, where `NR` it the total record number and `FNR` the record number in the current file.

You can build a key=value array `a` reading file2, and then when reading file1, set field 5 and field 6 if that value occurs in the array `a`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} 
{
  if ($5 in a) $5 = a[$5]
  if ($6 in a) $6 = a[$6]
} 1' file2 file1
```

If the contents of file1 is:

```
Create -l Ap -ne BP_v BP_v -cir {1 2 3 4}
Create -l Ap -ne BP_p BP_p -cir {1 2 3 4}
Create -l Ap -ne BP_v BP_p -cir {1 2 3 4}
```

The output will be:

```
Create -l Ap -ne net1 net1 -cir {1 2 3 4}
Create -l Ap -ne net2 net2 -cir {1 2 3 4}
Create -l Ap -ne net1 net2 -cir {1 2 3 4}
```

Answer (score 4):

***Generic solution:*** In this solution you can pass N number of fields which you want to change value in Input_file1 FROM Input_file2, in that case try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '
function passField(value,arrayVal){
  num=split(value,arrTemp,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if($vi in arrayVal){
       $i=arrayVal[$i]
    }
  }
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  passField("$5,$6",arr)
}
1
' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

---

---

***Specific solution(s) where only 5th and 6th field are being checked:***
With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. This will change 5th field of file2 as per file1 and if its NOT matched then it will print line as it is.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next}  {$5=($5 in arr)?arr[$5]:$5;$6=($6 in arr)?arr[$6]:$6} 1' Input_file2 Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                    ##This will be executed when file1 is being read.
  arr[$1]=$2                ##Creating array named arr with index of $1 and value of $2.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  $5=($5 in arr)?arr[$5]:$5 ##Checking if $5 of file2 present in array then change its value else keep it as it is.
  $6=($6 in arr)?arr[$6]:$6
}
1                           ##printing edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file2 Input_file1   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***OR*** In case you want to print only matched lines then try following code:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next}  ($5 in arr) && ($6 in arr){$5=arr[$5];$6=arr[$6];print}' Input_file2 Input_file1
```

Comment: Can you explain the working

Comment: @anonymous, sure, added detailed explanation for code, let me know in case of any queries here.

Comment: @anonymous, I have also added 1 Generic solution, same concept as previous solutions only thing it has function where we can pass all field numbers in a single shot itself.